# How would I use jQuery to manipulate a html form when there are nested elements involved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an empty form that needs to be filled with what I'd like to call mini-forms dynamically based on a condition. For example,this can be a form that asks for the names and locations of restaurants. Now, based on the number of restaurants(let's say 'm'), I'd like to add to the big form 'm' mini-forms that asks for the name and location.  How can I use jQuery to create each of these mini-forms, that take in the name and the location of the restaurant and append them each to the big form. The html would look something like this. But I need to create this dynamically based on how many forms the user would need, and if he would need any.

Edit - I have learned that we cannot nest forms. I have renamed the inner 'form' elements to 'div'.

```
<form>

<div id = 1> 
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name"> 
Location: <input type = "text" name ="location>
</div>

<div id = 2> 
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name"> 
Location: <input type = "text" name ="location>
</div>

... 
</form>
```

Comment: What are you doing with the form when it's submitted?

Comment: You can't nest forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: I intend to use the information, along with other information on the page, create a json object and send it to the backend for processing.

Comment: Well, you can't nest them _as forms_, but you can dynamically add inputs (and style them to look like separate forms)

Comment: Edited the question, now that I learned we cannot nest forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to look for changes to the input where the user enters the number of restaurants:

```
$('#noofrestaurants').change(function(){
```

Then you need to loop through the number inputted and create new inputs each time:

```
var restaurants = $('#noofrestaurants').val();
for (var i = 0; i < restaurants; i++){
$('#miniformcontainer').append('<input type="text" name="rest_name[]"/><input type="text" name="rest_loc[]"/>');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest forms. If you want to have repeated inputs in a form, give them array-style names:

```
<div id = 1> 
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name[]"> 
Location: <input type = "text" name ="location[]">
</div>
```

The back-end should convert these into arrays. For instance, PHP will fill in `$_POST['name']` with an array of all the `Name` inputs.

The jQuery looks like:

```
divnum++;
$("form").append("<div id='"+divnum+"'>Name: <input type='text' name='name[]'">Location: <input type='text' name='location[]'></div>");
```

Comment: Yeah, I changed the inner form elements in the question to 'div' once I was told I could not nest forms. However, I need to know how to do this dynamically with jQuery or javascript.

Comment: What's the problem? Just have jQuery append this DIV to the form.

Comment: I've added the jQuery to the answer.

Comment: Turns out I can't mark 2 answers as correct answers. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    <script>
    function addMiniForms(n)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n ; i++)
        {
            var $div = $("<div id='" + i + "'></div>");
            var $labelName = $("<label for='name" + i + "'>Name</label>");
            var $inputName = $("<input type='text' id='name" + i +' />");
            var $labelLocation = $("<label for='location" + i + "'>Location</label>");
            var $inputLocation = $("<input type='text' id='location" + i +' />");
            $div.append($labelName);
            $div.append($inputName);
            $div.append($labelLocation);
            $div.append($inputLocation);
            $("#containerid").append($div);
        };
    };
</script>
```

I have not tested this code, so it might need some tweaking.